# How to use in_field_map parameter of CreateCompositeAddressLocator_geocoding?

Tags: python, arcpy, arcgis-desktop, geocoding, field-mapping

I would like to know if anyone who has worked with the **[CreateCompositeAddressLocator_geocoding](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//002600000005000000)** method knows how the "in_field_map" parameter is formed?

Answer (score 1):

You can find an interesting [article](http://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2012/08/30/field-mapping-and-python-scripting/) from ESRI Python Team :

Otherwise the "Field Mappings" are explained [here](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/018z/018z00000078000000.htm) (with usefull examples at the end of the page):